Did the Buddha explicitly say "there is no self" is a wrong view?
I read the following on the internet:

Primary mistake is thinking that anattā means no soul or that "there
is no self". In Sabbāsavā Sutta the Buddha explicitly says that "there
is no self" is a wrong view born of inappropriate attention. "I am
nothing" or "I do not exist" is a wrong view born of asking the wrong
questions.

Did the Buddha explicitly say in Sabbāsavā Sutta "there is no self" is a wrong view?

I guess nothingness is one of the formless jhanas (absorption). So if one was to say everything is nothing, they are still clinging to a formless element.
Also Lord Buddha has the 10 unanswered questions, 6 of them are:

Is the being with a life force the same as the body?
Is the being with a life force not the same as the body?
Does the Tathagata exist after death?
Does the Tathagata not exist after death?
Does the Tathagata both exist and not exist after death?
Does the Tathagata neither exist nor not exist after death?

So basically, what we think of as a being is Suffering. Lord Buddha wants us to end suffering. So answering philosophical questions, or saying was is or is not, in regards to these things is a waste of time. What Lord Buddha does is point the way to end suffering. The Teachings are a raft that we use to realise that end.
What is temporary and fleeting is known as annica.
In what is temporary and fleeting their is suffering; dukkha.
In what temporary and fleeting, bound up with suffering, no happy eternal self or soul can be found, in any aspect of existence past, present or future.
Thus there are elements, but there is no self.
Their is action and the result of action; but there is no permanent lasting self-hood, all that is detected is change and alternation. The only thing outside this is the unconditioned element, known as Nibbana that is knowable only by the mind. That leads to the total extinction of suffering, on the break up of the body of an enlightened being.
So just saying I exist, or I don't exist, is all coming from wrong views. The raft of Dhamma is used to see these things clearly in one's own heart so one has inspiration in the Dhamma, and the joy to give up the world and identity for the sake of final peace or higher determination.

Yes. Pali for the wrong view : ‘natthi me attā’ti "there is no self (for me)." Since the Buddha often recommends thinking in terms of the first person, the "for me" is inconsequential. Thus the only thing wrong with it is the "There is no self."
He says this and the other views born of inappropriate attention is a:
diṭṭhigataṃ - diṭṭhigata: nt. (wrong or false) belief; misconception; theory; dogma; doctrine; lit. gone into views [diṭṭhi + gata] ✓
diṭṭhikantāraṃ - diṭṭhikantāra: masc. wasteland of views; desert of belief [diṭṭhi + kantāra] ✓
And many other terms that are synonymous with misguided views. It is a view born of the inappropriate attention concerning the existence of self.

I marked this answer down. It appears to make unsubstantiated inferences about the Buddha, as described in AN 2.23: https://accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an02/an02.023.than.html

Also SN 35.85 literally says the entire universe is empty of self: https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn35/sn35.085.than.html

The Buddha says his own "unrestricted awareness" is independent of and dissociated from the entire universe (loka) in Vāhuna sutta. He says that all arahants dwell with such an awareness, free from the cosmos, in several other Suttas eg. AN 3:106. The fact remains he explicitly says "there is no self" is a wrong view in two Suttas. No inferences are being made or required on my part.

Atthi means "exist" in Pali, by the way, not survive. Natthi me attā thus literally means "There is no self for me" or more colloquially in English we'd put it "I have no self." "Me" technically in the Pali dative catutthi so translating it as "for me" gives the most accurate idea of how the sentence would have been viewed at the time. Since there is nothing wrong with thinking in terms of "me" what's wrong is thinking "there is no self." Thus the wrong view is yours. Also the Buddha himself clarifies that disbelief in rebirth is one of the lowest wrong views in existence.

From Piya Tan's commentary to MN 2:

However, the view “no self exists for me” here is not the Buddha’s
non-self doctrine but the materialist view that identifies the
individual with his/her body, and thus holds that there is no personal
continuity after death.

Ven. Sujato commented here:

To be clear, the annihilationist view is that there is a self, but
that self is destroyed (usually at the time of death).

Based on this essay by Ven. Sujato and comments above it is evident that:

The Buddha taught "all phenomena is non-self" which implies there is no self.
Annihilationism is not about no self at all as a wrong view, but rather the self having existed, ceases to exist after some point in time as stated in DN 1 - "In this way some proclaim the annihilation, destruction, and extermination of an existent being".

Unfortunately, taking the literal translations of the suttas make it appear as though "no self exists for me" from MN 2 translated by Piya Tan or "there is no self" from SN 44.10 translated by Ven. Bodhi implies that "there is no self at all" is a wrong view. However, we are corrected here through traditional commentaries, just like in the case of "consciousness without surface", where traditional commentaries proved that it means "that which could be known" i.e. Nibbana.
The way I see it, "sabbe dhamma anatta" states that all phenomena is non-self (Piya Tan's preferred translation from here). That means there is no real self at all.
However, there is an illusionary self, a thought constructed by the mind, as implied by the notion “I am the thinker” from Snp 4.14 and birth (jati) of dependent origination.

i marked this answer down because the Buddha never used the word "materialist". The word "materialist" is only found in the sutta commentary Patisambiddhamagga and refers to "rebirth". Also, the word annihilation is not exclusively about death therefore Sujato's ideas sound misplaced.

The essay by Thanissaro Bhikkhu called 'Not-Self Strategy' is a misunderstanding of SN 44.10. Sujato criticizes these views at great length:

On not-self, existence, and ontological strategies

I just completed a new essay called Kaccānagotta Sutta - Existence and Non-Existence in the Pali Suttas; which also includes & conforms with the views of the Mahayana philosopher Nagarjuna. A relevant excerpt relating to this question is below:

The terms ‘atthi’ (‘exists’) and ‘natthi’ (‘not-exists’) are found
throughout the Pali Suttas, such as in:

SN 12.15, with the suffix ‘ta’, meaning ‘existence’ or ‘is-ness’ and ‘non-existence’ or ‘not-is-ness’.
SN 12.48, which refutes the ‘cosmologies/world-views’ (‘lokāyataṁ’) of ‘sabbam atthi’ and ‘sabbam natthi’.
SN 44.10, regarding two wrong views of ‘the self existing’ & ‘the self non-existing’ (atthattā and natthattā).
SN 12.17, in the statement: ‘suffering exists’ (atthi kho dukkhan’ti).
Ud 8.1, about Nibbana: ‘there exists that sphere’ (atthi tadāyatanaṁ).
MN 60, where ‘atthikavādo’ and ‘natthikavādo’ refer to moral doctrines of belief and non-belief (nihilism).

SN 12.15, SN 12.48 and SN 44.10 (listed above) refute ‘atthi’ and
‘natthi’ of ‘the world’, ‘self’ and ‘the all’ because these are not
real phenomena but instead are mere delusions.
SN 12.17, Ud 8.1 and MN 60 (listed above) do not refute the reality of
suffering, Nibbana or the moral laws of nature. These phenomena do
actually ‘exist’. Therefore, the term ‘atthi’ (‘exists’) can be
applied to them.
The Pali terms ‘sassatavādā’ (‘eternalism’) and ‘ucchedavādā
(‘annihilationism’), used in SN 44.10, SN 12.17 and DN 1, provide a
clear demonstration of the Buddha’s doctrine and therefore directly
explain how the similar worldly duality of ‘atthita’ (‘existence’) and
‘natthita’ (‘non-existence’) found in SN 12.15 are to be understood as two examples of
self-views that do not accord with ‘anatta’.
In SN 44.10, the wanderer Vacchagotta asks the Buddha two questions:
(i) does the self exist (atthattā)? and (ii) does the self not exist
(natthattā)? The Buddha refuses to answer the questions and, in his
explanation to Ananda, the Buddha explains why Vacchagotta’s  idea of
‘natthattā’ is ‘ucchedavādā (‘annihilationism’), namely, Vacchagotta
would have believed: “the self I formerly had now does not exist”.
This is exactly how Nagarjuna explained annihilationism, namely, "lt
does not exist now, but existed before".   In short, in SN 44.10, both
‘self/eternalism’ & ‘non-existing self/annihilationism’ are ‘self-views’, which is why they
are wrong views that do not accord with ‘anatta’ (‘not-self’).
Similarly, in SN 12.17, the wrong view ‘suffering is created by
oneself’  is deemed as ‘eternalism’ and the wrong view ‘suffering is
caused by another’ is deemed as ‘annihilationism’. Again, here, both
eternalism & annihilationism are ‘self-views’, which is why they are
wrong views that do not accord with ‘anatta’ (‘not-self’).
Similarly, in DN 1, the wrong view ‘the self & the world are eternal’
is deemed as ‘eternalism’. The wrong view deemed as ‘annihilationism’
is ‘this self (ayam attā) is annihilated and destroyed when the body
breaks up, and doesn’t exist after death... That is how some assert
the annihilation (ucchedam), destruction (vināsam) and non-existence
(vibhavam) of an existing being (sato sattassa)’’. Again, here, both
eternalism & annihilationism are ‘self-views’, which is why they are
wrong views that do not accord with ‘anatta’ (‘not-self’). As
Nagarjuna explained: “it is the change of the existent that people generally call the non-existent”.

The very same as above, all of the views below in the Sabbāsavā Sutta are self-views.

This is how he attends unwisely: ‘Was I in the past? Was I not in the
past? What was I in the past? How was I in the past? Having been what,
what did I become in the past? Shall I be in the future? Shall I not
be in the future? What shall I be in the future? How shall I be in the
future? Having been what, what shall I become in the future?’ Or else
he is inwardly perplexed about the present thus: ‘Am I? Am I not? What
am I? How am I? Where has this being come from? Where will it go?’
When he attends unwisely in this way, one of six views arises in him.

The view ‘the self exists for me (atthi me attā)’ arises in him as true and established;
the view ‘the self does not exist for me (natthi me attā)’ arises in him as true and established;
the view ‘I perceive self with self (attanāva attānaṁ)’ arises in him as
true and established;
the view ‘I perceive not-self with self (attanāva anattānaṁ )’
arises in him as true and established;
the view ‘I perceive self with not-self’ (anattanāva attānaṁ) arises in him as true and established; or else
he has some such view as this: ‘It is this self of mine (yo me ayaṁ attā) that speaks and feels and experiences here and there the result of good and bad actions; but
this self of mine is permanent, everlasting, eternal, not subject to
change, and it will endure as long as eternity.’

This speculative
view, bhikkhus, is called the thicket of views, the wilderness of
views, the contortion of views, the vacillation of views, the fetter
of views. Fettered by the fetter of views, the untaught ordinary
person is not freed from birth, ageing, and death, from sorrow,
lamentation, pain, grief, and despair; he is not freed from suffering,
I say.

Note: I corrected mistranslations of Bhikkhu Bodhi above. The phrase "natthi me attā" means:

the self does not exist for me.

my self does not exist.


It does not mean:

no self exists for me.

While Sujato appeared to suggest "reincarnation", by using the translation of 'not survive', his translation of the Sabbāsava Sutta at least correctly clearly demonstrates how "natthi me attā" is a self-view:

‘My self does not survive.’
‘natthi me attā’ti

